# new BigInteger(String) performance / complexity

Tags: java, performance, complexity-theory, biginteger

I'm wondering about the performance/**complexity** of **constructing BigInteger** objects with the `new BigInteger(String)` constructor.

Consider the following method:

```
  public static void testBigIntegerConstruction()
  {
    for (int exp = 1; exp < 10; exp++)
    {
      StringBuffer bigNumber = new StringBuffer((int) Math.pow(10.0, exp));
      for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(10.0, exp - 1); i++)
      {
        bigNumber.append("1234567890");
      }

      String val = bigNumber.toString();
      long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
      BigInteger bigOne = new BigInteger(val);
      System.out.println("time for constructing a 10^" + exp
          + " digits BigInteger : " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time))
          + " ms");
    }
  }
```

This method creates `BigInteger` objects of Strings with `10^x` digits, where `x=1` at the beginning, and it's increased with every iteration. It measures and outputs the time required for constructing the corresponding `BigInteger` object.

On my machine (Intel Core i5 660, JDK 6 Update 25 32 bit) the output is:

```
time for constructing a 10^1 digits BigInteger : 0 ms
time for constructing a 10^2 digits BigInteger : 0 ms
time for constructing a 10^3 digits BigInteger : 0 ms
time for constructing a 10^4 digits BigInteger : 16 ms
time for constructing a 10^5 digits BigInteger : 656 ms
time for constructing a 10^6 digits BigInteger : 59936 ms
time for constructing a 10^7 digits BigInteger : 6227975 ms
```

While ignoring the lines up to 10^5 (because of possible distortions introduced by (processor) caching effects, JIT-compilation etc), we can **clearly see a complexity of O(n^2)** here.
Keeping in mind that every operation on a `BigInteger` creates a new one due to immutability, **this is a major performance penality for huge numbers**.

**Questions:**

- Did I miss something?
- Why is this the case?
- Is this fixed in more recent JDKs?
- Are there any alternatives?

**UPDATE:**

I did further measurements and I can confirm the statement from some of the answers:
 It seems that `BigInteger` is optimized for subsequent numerical operations with the expense of higher construction costs for huge numbers which seems reasonable for me.

Comment: It seems plausible looking at the source code...

Comment: Have you measured using the non-String constructors, I am not sure that operations would serialize-deserialize to string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplifying from the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java#BigInteger.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String,int%29) somewhat, it's the case because in the "traditional" String parsing loop

```
for each digit y from left to right:
  x = 10 * x + y
```

you have the issue that `10 * x` takes time linear in the length of `x`, unavoidably, and that length grows by more-or-less a constant factor for each digit, also unavoidably.

(The actual implementation is somewhat smarter than this -- it tries to parse an `int`'s worth of binary digits at a time, and so the actual multiplier in the loop is more likely 1 or 2 billion -- but yeah, it's still quadratic overall.)

That said, a number with `10^6` digits is at least a googol, and that's bigger than any number I've heard of being used even for cryptographic purposes.  You're parsing a string that takes *two megabytes of memory*.  Yes, it'll take a while, but I suspect the JDK authors didn't see the point of optimizing for such a rare use case.

Answer (score 2):

The O(n^2) effort is caused by the decimal to binary conversion if the `BigInteger` is specified as decimal digits.

Also, 10^7 digits is a really huge number. For typical cryptographic algorithms like RSA you would deal with 10^3 to 10^4 digits. Most of the `BigInteger` operations are not optimized for such a large number of digits.

Comment: That is, your number would be of length `10^(10^7)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually measuring the time it takes to parse a string and create the BigInteger.  Numeric operations involving BigIntegers would be a lot more efficient than this.