# Printing BigIntegers to text files

Tags: java, performance, biginteger, println

I am calculating very big factorials in Java.However when I try to write them to text files it takes too much time. I'm using this method to print the numbers.

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(index + "!.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println(number);
writer.close();
```

Printing 10,000! to a text file takes 194 ms. The file size is 35.7 kB.

Printing 100,000! to a text file takes 24,314 ms. The file size is 456.6 kB.

I think the speed is too slow with this file size. How can I print BigIntegers with millions of digits in a few seconds? Are there faster methods or any way I can optimize this?

Comment: Java's BigInteger isn't well optimized for very large numbers. So you'll need to use a different library if you want the performance.

Comment: @Mysticial What is really damaging here is the conversion toString, see my answer.

Comment: 24,314 ms. => 24,314 *seconds*, more likely.

Comment: @laune Yeah I'm aware of that. Java BigInteger still uses the `O(N^2)` algorithm. They have yet to implement the `O(N*log(N)^2)` algorithm.

Comment: Technically a duplicate of [new BigInteger(String) performance / complexity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757086/new-bigintegerstring-performance-complexity) (a good overview).

Comment: Can someone show me where I can find libraries for this? I've been looking around for a while, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: @Mysticial I think that 1.8 has done something which look like it. Care to check? http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/math/BigInteger.java?av=f

Comment: @laune It looks like it will be `O(N^1.465 * log(N)^2)`. While it's not as fast as the state-of-the-art (`O(N*log(N)^2)`) it's much better than the current `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 3):

The time you observe is due to BigInteger.toString(), not the writing to the file.

Conversion of a looong BigInteger to a sequence of decimal (or any other base) digits is a cumbersome process, involving a looong division of a looong int[] by the base and composing the result string in a rather circumstantial way, even using a StringBuilder. (I just checked: 1.8 used an improved algorithm, but 35k or 456k digits is still a long way to go.)

I ran into this problem once and ended up writing my own BigInteger, using a representation that can be converted to base 10 very quickly.

If you opt for another library, make sure it permits operations that modify an object (rather than return a new object). If you expect frequent/long conversions to decimal string, try to find one that represents the numbers in a base that is an integral power of 10.

Comment: OT: interesting. Your own BigInteger was not base 10 in itself then?

Comment: @Jongware There's `BASE = 1000000000;` in that code. Good enough to test a number of 7008 digit numbers for being prime, and several other capers involving back-and-forth between binary computation and decimal representation.

Comment: I don't think that this is true **for every base**. In fact, I'm pretty sure that it will (or can) work much faster when a "power of 2" base is used, because no division operations are required in such case.

Comment: @barakmanos Interesting. Do you have a link to such an algorithm, e.g. converting a Java long to a String with decimal digits?

Comment: @laune: I said "power of 2" base (for example - 16). Decimal base is not included in that category!!!

Comment: @barakmanos int n = 0x12345; while( n > 0 ){ sb.insert(0,n&16); **n >>= 4;** } - A shift is also a division, maybe a little faster. - java.lang.Integer/Long.toString doesn't even bother to distinguish between bases 2^n and other bases.

Comment: @laune: That's why I said "or can" in my comment above. If `java.lang.Integer/Long.toString` doesn't distinguish between bases, then you can implement your own routine, to go over the bytes of the number and print each quantity of 4 bits (base 16) or 2 bits (base 4) or 1 bit (base 2), etc. Otherwise, iterating the number with division and modulo (which is inevitable for non "power of 2" bases) indeed takes considerably longer.

Comment: @barakmanos If you "go over the bytes" or nibbles or bit pairs or bits of an int or a long you still can't avoid a loop with a shift/division and mask/remainder. The only scenario where such a loop to convert from a 2^n base to a digit string is not necessary would be when it can be done 1:1, e.g., byte[] to base 256, etc. Nobody needs that anyway. - See my modification of "any other base" in the answer.

Comment: Your comparison is wrong. Going over the bytes with shifting and masking is done in O(n). Using the "standard" division and modulo, you have to calculate the entire number over and over again at each iteration. In other words, the values of **all** the bytes are recalculated after each time you calculate **one** digit. Try to implement `itoa` or something similar, and you'll note the difference.

Comment: @barakmanos I see what you mean - I lost the multiple int representation several comments ago from focus. - Going back to my answer, the statement "any other base" is regrettably true as it was made: referring to the JDK 1.6/1.7 implementations. 1.8 has improved this somewhat, but I haven't found a special procedure for bases like 2, 4, 16.

Comment: Like I said, just go over the bytes and calculate each digit using a simple mask. No need to compute an intermediate result after each digit (as you are forced to do when the base is not a power-of-2).

Comment: @barakmanos I don't need to do that because I'm not implementing JDK :-) Maybe you tell Oracle?

Comment: I meant to say, you (or OP) can implement your (or his/her) own routine for printing this number into a file, without relying on the `toString` implementation. But it is worthwhile only if he/she are willing to settle for a number in base 16 (for example).